# Noiseless home cloud low consumption VPN server in mid 2023

Tags: linux, vpn

I need a reliable hardware *box* to create an home cloud server, possibly Linux based.

The needs I would like to fullfil are:

- low energy consumption and noise (has to be turned on h24)
- usb port to add external drives.
- Possibly little size.

What it should offer

- VPN server. A must. While in travel the possibility to access the home network (so something that will update noip-like services).
- Service to Backup photo etc from android mobile  and files from laptop.
- Server for a local installation of sharelatex (with all LaTex)
- Possibly local dlna server.

I'm more oriented to a low budget solution upgradable with time.

What I found are unfortunately dated solutions.